# Keyboard eliminates the back button event - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have input on a `PhoneGap` app for `Android`.

when the keyboard is opened it must raise the screen up to see the Input, then see it just above the keyboard.

Once she makes it, the event I wrote to back button does not work anymore! And when I press a different input and the screen becomes normal, the event works ..

Maybe someone has an idea why this happens?

**I use PhoneGap 2.2.0 version - Android device 2.2 version**

Here my event:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    alert('U press back');
}, false);
```

Here my input:

```
<input type="text" id="MyInp"/>
```

Comment: why all your questions gets highlighted in the question list.?

Comment: this is the normal behaviour of Android. When keyboard is up, the back button is used to hide the keyboard. And this is the behaviour that users expect. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: I do not see it highlighted ..

Comment: I do not want to change it! After it hides the keyboard is supposed to arrive to my event, and he did not do it ..

Comment: Dont know why. but I've seen some of your previous questions also. when they appear in the newest question list, they are highlighted with yellow background.

Comment: I do not know why, for me it does not appear that way ..

Comment: The first back button should close the keyboard, the second back button should fire the "backbutton" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I added :

`android: windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan"`

in the Manifest.xml file,

I have no idea why .. **But it is solved!**

Comment: where to put it under which tag..? when i use it in activity tag not seems to solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Consider this, when you tap on the input box, Android performs an action of bringing in the keyboard on its own, because its the property of an input box.

The natural back button action is to undo the last action or to move to the previous page, etc. Hence, the default back button behaviour is to hide the keyboard.

Android doesn't provide a provision to override that action, it will always hide the keyboard if the focus lies within the input box.

Hope that helps.

@Sahil Mahajan Mj: the questions are highlighted because of the 100% accept rate. Hope mine gets accepted as well.

Comment: I do not want to override this event, when the keyboard is closed it is supposed to do my event .. And after it raises the input is forgetting that my event there and he takes me inside the app by pressing the back button